# std::vector crash in VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

Hi I am using `std::vector` and before installing VS 2012 it was running correctly (with VS 2013), but after installing VS 2012 I ran the same code

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        myVec.clear();
        myVec.push_back(v1);
        myVec.push_back(v2);
        myVec.push_back(v3);
        myVec.push_back(v4);
    }
}
```

for `i == 0` it runs and after that it is crashing. Have anyone met this problem?

In fact it is crashing after `if` and `i == 0` and it is saying

```
File: ...\dbgheap.c 
Line: 1424 
Expression: _pFirstBlock = pHead
```

Comment: What's the type of the object in `myVec`..? My guess would be that you're crashing when `myVec.clear()` is called and it's the destruction of the objects in the container that is causing the problem.

Comment: `std::vector<cv::Point>` and v1-3 are `cv::Point`

Comment: Can you post the code for `cv:Point` ?

Comment: cv::Point is from OpenCV and it runs fine on VS 2013

Comment: Please make a proper crashing test-case

Comment: @Sean: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#point

Comment: Alas, it blocked from where I work!

Comment: [check this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/75119478-b78b-4856-8638-c440cf38b75e/c-vector-memory-deallocation-problem-vs-2013-ultimate?forum=vclanguage) what happens in release mode?

Comment: could be you're using the release version of OpenCV with debug vc++

Comment: Yes, I think that was. I have rebuild it and redone the linking and it works